# Why is civilian GPS symmetrically encoded?

Tags: gps

Why is civilian GPS information symmetrically encoded? It is encoded using symmetric MAC, with the MAC key also being broadcast. This seems completely pointless.  Why don't they use private/public key signing, i.e. satellite signs with it's private key, we check using public key.

Comment: There was no production-ready public-key algorithm in the mid-70s.

Comment: If you disable the key broadcast, no one can use the gps any longer without the key - i would bet a pretty doller that every US-military GPS-device has such an private key embedded - But everybody else who could use GPS in a warfare situation does not.

Comment: Hi. Do you understand how CDMA (code division multiple access) works? The GPS signal is not 'encrypted' it is modulated with a PRS that creates separation between the signal from each satellite. The satellites all transmit on the same frequency at the same time. The ingenious bit is that the PRS codes themselves are used to triangulate - the actual data that is sent is not even important and could be anything.

Comment: @Jon, The actual data that is sent is unimportant to the position calculation algorithm, but the algorithm requires you to know the orbital elements (the trajectories) of the satellites with high precision in order to give a meaningful result. The actual data that is sent contains those orbital elements. So, yeah. At a _low_ level the actual data are irrelevant, but at a higher level, the actual data are essential.

Comment: @Jon but it's not "anything" is it.

Comment: @zeb3142 I guess my point is that a public key system wouldn't work because you need to know the 'key' to extract the signal out of the background noise. You can't  receive the message and then decrypt it to get the position fix. GPS just doesn't work like that. Encrypting the ephemeris and almanac data might slow someone down, but by their very nature (being big transmitters), it's not that hard to find out where the satellites are.

Answer (score 2):

Because civilian GPS signals can be turned off at any time, and nowadays can be selectively turned off over certain areas. So, if the people in charge want to deny civilian GPS, that's as simple as pressing the right key on a keyboard somewhere, almost.

> satellite signs with it's private key, we check using public key.

The only use of this - albeit perhaps a valid use - is to guard against signal spoofing. But then, you're denied GPS **anyway**, so the difference between a spoofed signal and no signal is academic.

If you depend on GPS in a "life and death" situation, you need to have fallbacks such as inertial navigation, celestial navigation, fixed known RF source triangulation, etc., and you need techniques to automatically detect deviation between GPS indications and redundant sources. So, in practice, where it actually matters, jamming and spoofing are equivalent and not much of a problem. As for a consumer device like a phone or navigation device getting spoofed data and misdirecting you: if you're a high value potential target, you can perhaps afford fallbacks :)

Comment: "Because civilian GPS signals can be turned off at any time" -- not sure that is relevant in many situations -- I would know if it was a "real" transmission, often that is all you need.